# Bing Maps MapControl not loading: GET https://www.bing.com/alse/rp/<random string>.br.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: bing-maps

I'm getting 404's from my own site (regardless of browser) as well as the [Bing Maps V8 Interactive SDK](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk). On my site this leads to `Uncaught TypeError: Microsoft.Maps.Location is not a constructor` errors. I'm guessing this means Bing Maps is having problems and not my code because of the missing .js file? Anything I can do to mitigate this?

Looks like Microsoft fixed their issue. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to reproduce this. Looks like Bing Maps is down. We can report this to the Bing Maps Enterprise support team here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/support (Bing Maps shows up under the developer tools category in the first form). I'll also report this from my end.

**Update**

The support team is now reporting that this issue has been resolved. I can confirm things are working on my end. I believe you can request details about the outage from the support team and they will send out an incident report once one is created (likely in the next couple of days).

Answer (score 1):

I have also reported this to Microsoft. All my screens that use the web controls have stopped working and report 404 problems on .js routines